# Is masturbating without thinking about someone haram?

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

I masturbate without fantasizing, just for the sake of pleasure and releasing tension. Is that haram?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: If masturbation is haram, then the way how or why you do it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Masturbating is a great sin! To release tension you must do more and more zikr. May Allah guide us all! If you start enjoying masturbation you will definitely be lured into other sins! hence we must restrain from this sinful act! In one of the book dedicated to this topic, it was written your hands will bear the womb as punishment! If you compare logically to this" lying to someone for the benefit of someone is also a sin" you can realize this is a sin too!